# Newrelic agent for Redis: newrelic_plugin -- have it installed, how to configure and run it?

Tags: newrelic

Installed ruby 2.3 on centos.

then:

gem install dante
gem install newrelic_plugin

It all installed, and is there.

Where do I configure it (add my app key, set my redis server name)?

How do I actually run it?

The readme is silent on this topics...

Comment: Did you get any result? i'm in the same issue now

Comment: Nope, we never got it to work and ended up dumping new relic and switching to data dog. New relic offers zero support for this piece

Comment: i found the way to install the plugin and it is working fine for me... The procedure is answered below for others. Can you please accept the answer so it will be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to install the newrelic redis plugin. This will be helpful for non-ruby background pros..

Follow the below steps to make it work.

Step 1 : Ensure that Ruby and gem is installed  on the computer on which you will install the Plugins for New Relic.

Step 2: Install the `bundle` Ruby gem.

Step 3: Create a directory in your computer where you want to place the plugin code downloaded from the git release page [here](https://github.com/kenjij/newrelic_redis_plugin/releases).

Step 4: In the config directory, make a copy of the template_newrelic_plugin.yml file and name it newrelic_plugin.yml

Step 5: Edit config/newrelic_plugin.yml and replace the string YOUR_LICENSE_KEY_HERE with your New Relic license key

Step 6: In config/newrelic_plugin.yml file, set the configuration properties for your redis server.

Few configuration options are available in `config/newrelic_plugin.yml`.

`instance_name` – Name of the instance that will be listed in New Relic

`url` – Your Redis server; use "redis://127.0.0.1:6379" as default

`database` – the database in which to lookup 'total keys'; use "db0" as default

Step 7: From the top-level directory, run the following commands

```
bundle install
./newrelic_redis_agent
```

Other command line options are:

```
-d – Run as daemon
-c FILE – Designate a config file
```

That's it wait for some time and check your new relic account under plugins tab.